# Subtracting two dict values in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I have two dict

```
${Dict1}={'Test_1': {'l': 307, 'T': 290, 'R': 5785, 'Bo': 4693} ,'Test_2': {'l': 307, 'T': 290, 'R': 5785, 'B': 4693}} 
${Dict2}={'TestB_3': {'l': 310, 'T': 295, 'R': 5785, 'Bo': 4693} ,'TestB_4': {'l': 307, 'T': 290, 'R': 5785, 'B': 4693}}
```

I want to subtract and get the result something like this ${Dict1}-${Dict2}

```
${Result} = {'Test_1': {'l': -3 , 'T': -5, 'R': 0, 'Bo': 0} ,'Test_2': {'l': 0, 'T': 0, 'R': 0, 'B': 0}
```

I know how to do in Python , But in Robot framework, I am not getting an idea

In Python ,

We do something like

```
for key1,Key2 in zip(dict1.key, dict2.key):
     result[key1]=dict[Key1]-dict[key2]
```

### Is there anything like this in ROBOT framework in python

**Updating some more info**

```
${x2}    Create Dictionary    x2=2
${x1}    Create Dictionary    x1=5
FOR    ${key_of_Orginal}    ${key_of_Actual}    IN ZIP    @{x2}    @{x1}
Log    ${key_of_Orginal}
Log    ${key_of_Actual}
END
```

Will give this error

```
Starting test: ManualMargin.Test1.Test8
20200410 14:41:52.061 :  INFO : ${x2} = {'x2': '2'}
20200410 14:41:52.063 :  INFO : ${x1} = {'x1': '5'}
20200410 14:41:52.064 :  FAIL : FOR IN ZIP items must all be list-like, got string.
Ending test:   Test8
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be write a function in Python like below and adding it to user defined library and importing that library where you want to use it.

```
def sub_dict(dict1, dict2):
    result = {}
    for tuple in zip(dict1.keys(), dict2.keys()):
        result[tuple[0]] = dict1[tuple[0]] - dict2[tuple[1]]
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

Your python code in Robot Framework format:

```
FOR    ${key1}    ${key2}    IN ZIP    ${dict1}    ${dict2}
    ${value}=    Evaluate    $dict1[$key1] - $dict2[$key2]
    Set do Dictionary    ${result}    ${key1}    ${value}
END
```

As you can see, the syntax is almost the same here.

There's a strong dependency in the approach you've taken - that both dictionaries have the same keys, they are in the same order, and that order is preserved in retrieving them (the last one is applicable to python version 3.6+). Otherwise you may be subtracting the values of different keys.
A more solid one would be to iterate over the keys of only one of the two, make sure it exists in the second, and do the calculation just then. E.g.:

```
FOR    ${key1}    IN    @{dict1}
    ${exists}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Dictionary Should Contain Key    ${dict2}   ${key1}
    Continue For Loop If    not ${exists}    # the other doesn't have it, cannot do the calc
    ${value}=    Evaluate    $dict1[$key1] - $dict2[$key1]
    Set do Dictionary    ${result}    ${key1}    ${value}
END
```

Comment: `FOR IN ZIP items must all be list-like, got string` I am seeing this error. I tried the first way

Comment: The `${dict1}` and `${dict2}` variables must be proper dictionaries, you most probably are passing a string that's json.

Comment: I am taking the Dict1 and Dict2 as a argument in my keyword which is in the format as above . Like this `[Arguments]         ${Dict1}       ${Dict2}`

Comment: Just for more info , I logged the variable before it enters in for loop it is like this. 
`{'C:\page268.tif': {'L': 307, 'T': 290, 'R': 5785, 'B': 4693}}` . This is the same format case another variable also .

Comment: `IN ZIP` expects a variable reference, not expanded one; I've updated the answer with that.

Comment: i have updated Robot code also in my question, please look to it

Comment: Now the simple code worked , for my basic question which have DIctonary inside the dictionary, I am seeing this error `'RF_VAR_dict1 [RF_VAR_key1 ]- RF_VAR_dict2 [RF_VAR_key2 ]' failed: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DotDict' and 'DotDict' ` I think , i need to iterate once again , i will also try

Comment: Please don't do that, the question's body is not a discussion board. See what I changed in the answer, the way the variables are referenced in `IN ZIP` is through `$`, not with `@`

Comment: Yeah! I agree, just to simply the question, I edited as we had a doubt whether we are using proper dict or not. After your change, a new error is occurring, as I mentioned in the above comment

Comment: It's not simplified, on the contrary, it's now 2 questions in one. There are now a few problems, that you should eventually fix yourself: the actual dictionary you've shown a couple of comments up is a dictionary of dictionary - you have to iterate over the `'C:\page268.tif'` key. The dictionary you've used as a sample in the updated question has as values not integers, like in the original question, but strings - and you cannot do subtraction on strings. Nevertheless, I'm stopping here, the discussion got sidetracked.

Comment: No ! `c:\page268.tif` is test1 in basic question. But fine,I got the hint . Thanks 